# Is there a way to display a DiGraph object on a Shiny app?

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, py-shiny

I'm using Shiny for Python, and it cannot load a graphviz object so I have been trying to find workarounds.

I have been trying to convert it to an image, which Shiny can recognize.

I am using the lingam package to draw a graph and have tried the code written [here](https://lingam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/draw_graph.html#:%7E:text=dot.format%20%3D%20%27png%27%0Adot.render(%27dag%27)). Render works, and the file is saved as a png, but the app closes immediately for some reason. Since I wanted to test out the attribute "draw", which was suggested in various forums online, I have tried using pygraphviz, but this too does not seem to not have that object either.

Please let me know if anyone has found a solution to this!